# Как сообщить пользователю дополнительную информацию при оплате (ruby on rails, liqpay)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, реализовал оплату с помощью liqpay.
На почту после оплаты приходит сообщение с полями суммы, получателя, номера телефона, назначения, даты платежа и ИД. Но можно ли добавить в чек дополнительные поля?

```
def check_payment_status
  if @place.status == false
    @liqpay_request = Liqpay::Request.new(
      :amount => @searched_film_session_price,
      :currency => 'UAH',
      :description => @place_title,
      :order_id => @place.id,
      :sandbox => 1,
      :info => "test info",
      :result_url => place_url(@place)
      # :server_url => liqpay_payment_place_url(@place)
    )
  end
end
```

Добавил поле :info, в [документации](https://www.liqpay.com/ru/doc/pay) оно есть, но в чек не добавляеться.
Как сообщить пользователю дополнительную информацию?

Comment: А чек откуда приходит?

Comment: Чек приходит от  liqpay.

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, вам к ним в техподдержку.

Comment: Я не знаю про liqpay, но, например в робокассе этот параметр был только для системы. Содержимое передавалось обратно в приложение в запросе подтверждающем платеж.